# Collecting remainders while converting a number to ternary base ( C++ )

Tags: c++, decimal, radix, ternary

I am trying to write a program in C++. It's a much longer program, but I need help regarding just one of the functions in it.

Basically, this function should get a number, and then return that same number but in ternary base. Now, my idea is to basically divide that number by 3 and collect remainders ( if my number is "n", I'd use n%3) and then I would just divide that number with 3 ( n/3 ) and go again until that number "n" by repeated division becomes 0.

This should work and convert the number to ternary base, but my problem is the fact that I do not know how to collect these remainders. This is probably a stupid question, but I am still a begginer in programming.

Basically, if I make a while loop , something like this :

```
while(n>0) 
{
 int digitofternary=n%3;
 n/=3;
}
```

In every iteration of while loop, digitofternary is just going to change. How can I adjust this loop so digits get remembered/collected and I can return a new normal ternary base number from function?

Sorry if this sounded confusing, hope it didn't ( I am not a native english speaker ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sample_fn (int n) 
{ 
    std::string str_ret;
    while(n>0) 
    {
       int digitofternary=n%3;
       n/=3;
       std::string str= std::to_string(digitofternary);
       str_ret.append(str); 
    }
    return std::stoi(str_ret);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I basically want to return a whole number ( made of those ternary numbers/remainders ). Vectors could maybe work, but I would need somehow to convert that whole vector to a number?

Comment: i modified my answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: It is. Thank you so much .